# Jetpack Compose how to collect flows from the view model and action them in composables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

ViewModel:

```
    class RulesViewModel : ViewModel() {
        private val _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<ScreenEvents>()
        val sharedFlow = _sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()

        sealed class ScreenEvents {
            data class ShowSnackbar(val message: String) : ScreenEvents()
            data class Navigate(val route: String) : ScreenEvents()
        }
    }
```

Composable:

```
@Composable
fun EventListener(
    rulesVm: RulesViewModel,
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        rulesVm.sharedFlow.collect { event ->
            when(event) {
                is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.ShowSnackbar -> {
                    SnackbarScreen("snackbar ${event.message}")
                }
                is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.Navigate -> {
                    // todo
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error message: *@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function*

What is the best practice for collecting flows then from viewModels and actioning them in composables?

Comment: How do you call `EventListener` function?

Comment: I call it in `FragmentRules`, which I call this way: `setContent {
                SnookerBoardTheme {
                    GenericSurface {
                        FragmentRules(rulesVm)
                    }
                }
            }`

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use extension - Flow.**collectAsState()**

In Your case it will be:

```
val screenState = rulesVm.sharedFlow.collectAsState
```

Then in the body of a composable function You go:

```
@Composable
fun EventListener(
rulesVm: RulesViewModel,
) {
    val screenState = rulesVm.sharedFlow.collectAsState()
    
    when(screenState) {
             is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.ShowSnackbar -> {
                 SnackbarScreen("snackbar ${event.message}")
             }
             is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.Navigate -> {
                 // todo
             }
    }
}
```

You can't invocate composable function inside LaunchedEffect body and inside Flow.collect() because it's an extension on coroutine scope, not a composable function.

Comment: With some adjustments, such as `val screenState = rulesVm.sharedFlow.collectAsState(RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.Initial)` and `SnackbarScreen((screenState.value as RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.ShowSnackbar).message)`, this works, but it still only registers the first event; if another event of the same time is emitted, it will not be detected

Comment: You mean providing initial state in composable function?
No, it's wrong. You must provide it in ViewModel because it manages UI state in MVI. You also don't need to cast any state value to some class, because it's necessary almost only in when() statement. I think that MVI on compose is not clear to You, so I would like to recomment to read some topics about it on medium or google.developer.com.

Comment: `collectAsState` is the only solution for calling another Composable upon emission.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you would like to see is the following behavior: you dispatch an event and the snackbar appears on the current screen without going to the another screen. If you do not need to take into account the application lifecycle when receiving events, then the example below will suit you. I create a scaffoldState, which I use to display the Snaskbar. The subscription occurs once due to the fact that Unit is an object.

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    rulesVm.sharedFlow.collect { event ->
        when(event) {
            is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.Navigate -> TODO("Add navigation to another screen")
            is RulesViewModel.ScreenEvents.ShowSnackbar -> 
                scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = "snackbar ${event.message}"
                )
        }
    }
}

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = { snackbarHostState ->
        SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData = data
            )
        }
    }
) {
    TODO("Add your screen content")
}
```